# DLL Export Function Called Twice

Tags: c, dll

I have made a short DLL which will display a MessageBox when it is loaded by a process. However, the message box is displayed two times. So, it looks like the DLL Export Function is called twice. Could you please see if there is something that needs to be modified in my code so that the MessageBox is displayed only once?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void sampledllmain()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "sample text","sample title", 0);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hHandle, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    switch(dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                sampledllmain();
                break;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I load the DLL using rundll32 as shown below:

```
rundll32 "path to DLL",sampledllmain
```

Comment: your invocation is calling `sampledllmain` with `DllMain` and with the `rundll32` invocation, please add a second dummy function for your tests so you can use `rundll32 "path to DLL",dummy`

Comment: Of course it would be called twice. Remove `sampledllmain` from the `DllMain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by the [information page about rundll32.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787) :

> 1. It loads the specified DLL via `LoadLibrary()`.
> 2. It obtains the address of the  function via `GetProcAddress()`.
> 3. It calls the  function, passing the command line tail which is the .

In your case :

1. When [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) is invoked it calls [`DllMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx), in your case `DllMain` calls `sampledllmain`.
2. Obtains the address of `sampledllmain`
3. calls `sampledllmain` ( second time ).

to fix your issue:

- add a second function `dummy` (for example )
- use `rundll32 "path to DLL",dummy` on the command line

PS: On an additional note you could also debug your dll there are [guides that describe how to do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt.aspx)

An example with `MessageBox` call in `dllMain`

```
#include <windows.h>
__declspec(dllexport) void sample(void)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "sample text test", "sample title test", 0);
}
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(NULL, "attach", "DllMain", 0);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        MessageBox(NULL, "detach", "DllMain", 0);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Run with `rundll32.exe lib.dll,sample`

Comment: I want the MessageBox to displayed when the DLL is loaded by the Process. But when I place the call to MessageBox directly in the DllMain function it is called 4 times. I read somewhere that we should create a different export function for it and invoke it from DLL main based on a condition like DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. So, how do I display the Message Box on the call to DllMain()?

Comment: but why do you invoke it a second time with `rundll32.exe` ( passing it as a parameter ) ?

Comment: I use rundll32 only for testing. How can I execute MessageBox function only once when a DLL is loaded? When LoadLibrary() is used to load a DLL, DllMain() function is called automatically. So, ideally, if I place a call directly inside DllMain() for MessageBox, then it should execute MessageBox() only once right? Why does it happen two times or more times then? You can test this yourself.

Comment: couldn't you add another function, and call it with rundll32 instead of `sampledllmain` ?

Comment: My guess is that your multiple call to message box have to do with the different call to `DllMain` with different `dwReason`